# iTunesConnect submission of an iPad only app gives validation error: MainWindow~iPhone.xib not found

Tags: ipad

The app is iPad only and I have submitted the same app before.
Why do I get this error? How can I fix the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is not entirely true: I have combined sources for iPhone and iPad  with 2 targets. I had build the target for iPad.

Comment: Also i was using Xcode 6.3 which is in beta. Now trying with 6.1.1.